# How to save data to the same model from forms in different pages...Registration multiple fields? Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

i'm trying to make a user registration with multiple fields to save in the same model. The idea is have a form in the home page with username and password and when press button continue the user is redirected to another page with multiple fields to  insert personal info for the user profile.
I imagine i must have two different views for that, but i don't understand how put all this data together.

Thanks!

Comment: The first page is model USER, and the second is model PROFILE?

Comment: No is just one model, my idea is start collecting data username and password from home page and than redirect to another page with multiple fields, and put data from different pages in the same model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the FormWizard (https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html)

Basically you would have one form for user/password and another form for the other fields. 
Take a look

Answer (score 0):

In your case i would prefer manipulate HTML content with JavaScript and after everything is ready, just send an ajax call.